# Como activar la edicion en vivo con spring boot

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Estoy trabajando en spring boot con gradle y no se como activar la edicion en vivo investigue que se tiene que integrar la dependecia

```
 compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
```

pero no logro hacerla funcionar no se que pueda estar haciendo mal

Answer (score 0):

No conozco `gradle` pero en `Maven` es:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Asi que supongo que en `gradle` le debes de indicar que el `scope` es `runtime` en lugar del `compile` que tienes.